# PHP - Nested Looping Trouble

Tags: php, for-loop, nested

I have an HTML table that I need to populate with the values grabbed from a select statement.
The table cols are populated by an array (0,1,2,3).
Each of the results from the query will contain a row 'GATE' with a value of (0-3), but there will not be any predictability to those results. One query could pull 4 rows with 'GATE' values of 0,1,2,3, the next query could pull two rows with values of 1 & 2, or 1 & 3.

I need to be able to populate this HTML table with values that correspond. So HTML COL 0 would have the TTL_NET_SALES of the db row which also has the GATE value of 0.

```
<?php

$gate = array(0,1,2,3);
$gate_n = count($gate);

/*
Database = 
my_table.ID
my_table.TT_NET_SALES
my_table.GATE
my_table.LOCKED
*/

$locked = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE locked = true";
$locked_n = count($locked);

/* EXAMPLE RETURN

Row 1:
my_table['ID'] = 1
my_table['TTL_NET_SALES'] = 1000
my_table['GATE'] = 1;

Row 2:
my_table['ID'] = 2
my_table['TTL_NET_SALES'] = 1500
my_table['GATE'] = 3;
*/

print "<table border='1'>";
print "<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>";
print "<tr>";

for ($i=0; $i<$locked_n; $i++)
{
    for ($g=0; $g<$gate_n; $g++)
    {
        if (!is_null($locked['TTL_NET_SALES'][$i]) && $locked['GATE'][$i] == $gate[$g]) {
            print "<td>$".$locked['TTL_NET_SALES'][$i]."</td>";

        } else {
            print "<td>-</td>";
        }
    }
}

print "</tr>";
print "</table>";

/*
What I want to see:
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>-</td>
<td>1000</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>1500</td>
</tr>
</table>
*/

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an error in your code... Replace `$col<$my_cols;` by `$col < count($my_cols)`

```
$my_cols = array(0,1,2,3);
for($i = 0; $i<$db_res; $i++)
{
    for($col = 0; $col<$my_cols; $col++)
    {
        if ($db_res[$i] == $col) {
            print "<td>".$db_res[$i]."</td>";
        } else {
            print "<td>-</td>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No it didn't. It was just a typo, but the problem remains.

Comment: This may help: $my_cols = array(0,1,2,3); $db_res = array(1,2); I want the results to look like this 0:x, 1:1, 2:2, 3:x.

Comment: You could use a function called `array_diff`. Check out more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: The $db_res array will contain other array elements taken from my db. So it will actually look more like $db_res['var1'][$i], $db_res['var2'][$i], etc. And I'm trying to compare $my_cols to $db_res['var1'][$i].

Comment: Yeah, that function works well with stuff from database too... Give it out a try... :)

Comment: Still having trouble with this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistakenly looping through the second array to check for equality, when array_search was all that I needed. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

```
print "<table border='1'>";
print "<tr>";

$my_arr = array(0,1,2,3);

$vals = array(1,2);

for ($i = 0; $i<count($my_arr); $i++) 
{  
    print "<td>";
    $key = array_search($my_arr[$i], $vals);
    if (is_int($key)){
        print $vals[$key];
    } else {
        print "-";
    }
    print "</td>";
}

print "</tr>";
print "</table>";
```